# What are these relays for?

Tags: car

can anyone confirm what that black box between the writing DLC plug and Air filter. it has 3 relays in their. Mine are[image] missing and not sure which ones go in there.

Comment: Is there a legend inside the lid? If not, then the user or workshop manual will usually shown the type of relay and rating, have you checked?

Comment: thanks for replying. sorry about the other msgs, first time im using this.

Comment: there are 3 connections, however there are no relays in there. the car has been parked for around 5 years and dont start. i wasnt sure if there are suppose to be in their. Also i dont have user or workshop manual

Comment: A quick search gives this: https://fuse-box.info/bmw/bmw-5-series-e39-1996-2003-fuses-and-relay

Comment: thanks its a e34 1995, ill see what google has for me. Thanks for you support.

Comment: After 5 years the fuel has turned to varnish, it may need a fuel tank flush and new fuel pump.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the relays in that box

[image]